# Adding classes with PHP echo, not replacing them

Tags: php

First of all, I know this is simple but I'm not a PHP developer by trade so I apologize if this is dumb for everyone. That being said, I've spent the last 3 hrs searching and can't find a way to do this without re-inventing my wheel so to speak. I use a simple command to mark the navigation on websites when the page is "current".

```
<li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'page')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="page.php" class="tp">Page</a></li>
```

Works great in most cases. However in this case, I need to concatenate the class string, not overwrite it with current. I've tried

```
...echo'class=" "."current".'
```

and several variations and can't get it to simply add the class not overwrite it. Thank you

Comment: I'm not totally sure what the problem is. Are you saying you want to add several classes rather than one, but based on a php variable? Once you further explain your question, I should be able to give a better answer =]

Comment: Also, the difference between ' and " in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @Relequestual kind of. I need a class on the <a> element to bring in the appropriate bg icon. I need to add the class 'current' to it w/o removing the class it already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
<li>
    <a href="page.php" 
      class="<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'page')) {echo 'current ';} ?>tp">
        Page
    </a>
</li>
```

This way, you'll always have at least `class="tp"`, and, if the condition is met, a `'current '` *(note the space at the end of this string : it's important and required so the two classes are separated by a space and not considered as one)* will be inserted just before the `'tp'`, inside the `class="..."`

Comment: I've edited my answer, trying to provide a bit more information. Basically, you'll always have `class="tp"` ; and only add `'current'` when needed ; which seems to be what you were trying to get.

Comment: Pascal, very nice thank you I should have looked at it this way originally. I appreciate the explanation, and the help. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `<li>` not in a loop?

Ideally your menu would come from a table array through which you would loop. If that is the case; try this:

```
foreach(..){
    $class = strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'page') ? " current" : "";
    echo "<li><a href=\"page.php\" class=\"tp" . $class . "\">Page</a></li>";
}
```

Overall, for readability, I would recommend to not put `if` statements inline in the HTML.

But based on your code:

```
<?php 
$class = strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'page') ? " current" : "";
?>
<li><a href="page.php" class="tp<?php echo $class; ?>">Page</a></li>
```

Comment: ATM, the navigation is static and not pulled in dynamically. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: Cool. I would recommend to at least put your nav in an array and loop through that, to prevent redundant code.

Comment: I would love to know how to do that, but atm i do not. I'm doing good just to stick the nav in an php include!

Comment: Sure, all in good time :-) If you are interested in improving your skills, have a look here: http://www.finalwebsites.com/tutorials/css-navigation-bar.php

Comment: Richard - I'm always interested in improving. Thank you for the link and sharing the knowledge!

Comment: Cool, using an array for your menu is really very easy and one of the basics of PHP. This is also a good one about array's and iterating through them: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/foreach.php